What does 'gloated over' mean in this Tom Sawyer quote?
What does 'gloated' mean in the following quote from Tom Sawyer:

It was talked about, gloated over, glorified, until the reason of many
of the citizens tottered under the strain of the unhealthy excitement.

To provide some context, Tom and Huck found a big sum of money, and the city was 'gloating over' their find.
I found out that 'gloat' means "to take satisfaction in another's misfortune".
But they found a treasure, which is quite fortunate. How does 'gloated over' fits there?
Quote:

THE reader may rest satisfied that Tom's and Huck's windfall made a
mighty stir in the poor little village of St. Petersburg. So vast a
sum, all in actual cash, seemed next to incredible. It was talked
about, gloated over, glorified, until the reason of many of the
citizens tottered under the strain of the unhealthy excitement. Every
"haunted"  house  in  St.  Petersburg  and  the  neighboring  villages
was  dissected, plank by plank, and its foundations dug up and
ransacked for hidden treasure  — and  not  by  boys, but  men  —
pretty  grave,  unromantic  men, too,  some  of  them. Wherever Tom
and Huck appeared they were courted, admired, stared at. The boys were
not  able  to  remember  that  their  remarks  had  possessed  weight
before;  but now  their  sayings  were  treasured  and  repeated;
everything  they  did  seemed somehow to be regarded as remarkable;
they had evidently lost the power of doing and  saying  commonplace
things;  moreover,  their  past  history  was  raked  up  and
discovered to bear marks of conspicuous originality. The village paper
published biographical sketches of the boys.


As Merriam-Webster says, gloat means “to observe or think about something with triumphant and often malicious satisfaction, gratification, or delight.” So here Twain is saying that the townspeople celebrated vicariously, and probably that they felt themselves better (by association with the fortunate boys) than their acquaintances in nearby towns.

Can I clarify that when dictionary definitions say 'often' they mean 'but not always', so that to gloat in M-W means "to observe or think about something with triumphant satisfaction, gratification, or delight that is often, but not always, malicious”.

Good clarification, @MichaelHarvey.

The meaning of gloat has changed with time. According to the OED it originally (16th C) meant to look at furtively, then to look at admiringly or amorously, then "to gaze with intense or passionate satisfaction". The 1913 Webster's dictionary is closer to Twain's time than the modern dictionary, and its definition is "To look steadfastly; to gaze earnestly; -- usually in a bad sense, to gaze with malignant satisfaction, passionate desire, lust, or avarice." Now its main sense is excessive celebration or taking pleasure in others' loss.

Fascinating, @StuartF. So my reading may have been at least in part an ascribing of a modern meaning to an earlier usage. Like one of the reasons John McWhorter argues that Shakespeare should be performed in translation—into English, to wit, “English has changed so deeply since Shakespeare’s time that today we are incapable of catching much more than the basic gist of a great deal of his writing, although the similarity of the forms of the words to ours tricks us into thinking otherwise.”

Gloating involves a feeling of superiority on the part of the gloater. Now the citizens of the small village of St Petersburg (an ironic name for a tiny place) feel they have something that they can "lord over" other towns. Doesn't such gloating reveal something about the smallness of the place and the parochialism of its proud boosters?
